# Is there a standard command to pause and continue or abort?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am looking for what `foo` may be in:

```
$ echo blah && foo && echo the sequel
blah
Do you want to continue? [y/n]: n
$ echo blah && foo && echo the sequel
blah
Do you want to continue? [y/n]: y
blah
$
```

Comment: Here are some additional tips for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard? No.

You could do

```
foo() {
    local answer
    while true; do
        read -p "Do you wish to continue? [y/n]: " answer
        case $answer in
            [yY]*) return 0 ;;
            [nN]*) return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
}
```